# alert if no results is found in saved array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fetch data from an api which the first loads for the first time and save it in an array. Then when a user specifics the date range he/she would like to search from i display the results into the view from the saved array based on what the user specified. its working perfectly but the issue is i'm able to display an error message when the user search yield no results

```
.controller('billing_statement_ctrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $cordovaToast, $location, $ionicModal, $filter) {
    $scope.account_number = localStorage.getItem("account_number");
    ///alert if connection fails
    $scope.connect = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error',
        template: '<p align="center">Problem Contacting Server</p>',
      });
    };

    $scope.state_request = function() {
      $http.post("http://localhost/server/statement.php", {
        'id': $scope.account_number
      }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.record = data;
      })

      $scope.from = $filter('date')($scope.sdate, "yyyy-MM-dd" + 'T00:00:00') + 'Z';
      $scope.to = $filter('date')($scope.edate, "yyyy-MM-dd" + 'T00:00:00') + 'Z';


    }

  })

  .filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, from, to) {
      return records.filter(function(record) {
        return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;
        if (record == '') {
          alert('its empty')
        } else {
          alert('results found')
        }
      });
    }
  })
```

with my script when its successful or unsuccessful i get not alert.

and secondly when the page loads i get this error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get an alert because you have a `return` before the conditional that triggers the alerts.

Code after a `return` in a function doesn't execute. Also don't use `alert()` for debugging...use `console` methods like `console.log()`

As for the initial load , the filter is being run on an undefined input value , probably because the variable in view isn't defined until an http request completes. Thus it isn't an array yet and the error is telling you you can't use array methods on it

Adjust your custom angular filter to return null or an empty array if the input is undefined.

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, from, to) {
      // return empty array if input not defined or not array
      if(!records || !angular.isArray(records)){
         return [];
      }
      var results = records.filter(function(record) {
         // run console log tests here...before the return
        return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;        
      });
      console.log( 'Number of results:', results.length);
      return results;
    }
})
```